# powershell - combine array properties in new one

Tags: powershell

I have some array with lot of rows (thousands and more). It have columns like 'Column**XXXXX**'

Row example:

```
Group_name = "proxy_users"
Column1   = "domain\Igor"
Column2   = null
.......
Column989 = 'domain\Andrew'
Column999 = 'domain\Mike'
```

What is the right and FAST way to create new variable that will be the sum of 'ColumnXXX' ignoring 'null' values?

Like "domain\igor, domain\Andrew, domain\mike"

I can use smth like $group | select -Property "Column*"...but how to sum and how to ignore null ?

Comment: Is it actually `$null` or a "null" string-value?

Comment: "null" string-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list all properties using ex. `$_.psobject.properties`, filter out the ones you want and use `-join` to combine the values. Ex

```
$o = [pscustomobject]@{
    Group_Name = "Test"
    Column1 = "Foo"
    Column2 = $null
    Column3 = "1"
}, [pscustomobject]@{
    Group_Name = "Test2"
    Column1 = $null
    Column2 = "Bar"
    Column3 = "2"
}

#Add property as constant
$o | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Summed -NotePropertyValue (($_.psobject.Properties | Where-Object { $_.Name -ne 'Group_name' -and $_.Value -ne 'null' } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value) -join '' )
}
$o | ft
```

Or you can use a ScriptProperty to calculate the value on every call

```
#Remember to exclude itself to avoid infinite recursion
$o | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name Summed -Value {($this.psobject.Properties | Where-Object { $_.Name -ne 'Group_name' -and $_.Name -ne 'Summed' -and $_.Value -ne 'null' } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value) -join '' }
$o | ft
```

Result:

```
Group_Name Column1 Column2 Column3 Summed
---------- ------- ------- ------- ------
Test       Foo             1       Foo1
Test2              Bar     2       Bar2
```

As an alternative, you can use `$_.Name -like 'Column*' -and $_.Value -ne 'null'` as the property-filter if they are actually called `ColumnXXX`.

Answer (score 0):

To complement [Frode F.'s elegant ScriptProperty-based solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48851900/45375) with a more concise PSv4+ version that also performs better due to avoiding the use of cmdlets (a *pipeline*) in the property-definition script block in favor of *operators* (with a large number of input objects, this may matter):

```sh
$o | Add-Member -PassThru -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name Joined -Value { 
 @($this.psobject.Properties.Where({$_.Name -match 'Column*'}).Value) -ne 'null' -join ', ' 
}
```

Note the use of:

- The `.Where()` collection operator (PSv4+), a faster alternative to the `Where-Object` cmdlet.
- [*Member-access enumeration*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375) (PSv3+), where accessing a property at the *collection* level yields an *array* of the *elements'* property values;
  e.g., `$this.psobject.Properties.Name` yields the `.Name` property values of all elements of the `$this.psobject.Properties` collection.
- Applying comparison operator `-ne` to an *array-valued* LHS, in which case the operator acts as a *filter*: the operator is applied to *each element*, and the matching elements are returned as an array; note the `@(...)` around the LHS, which ensures that it is treated as an array even if it happens to return only a single value.

With the sample data in the question, the above yields (look for property `Joined`):

```sh
Group_name : proxy_users
Column1    : domain\Igor
Column2    : null
Column989  : domain\Andrew
Column999  : domain\Mike
Joined     : domain\Igor, domain\Andrew, domain\Mike
```

---

With the above optimizations, you could even consider a simpler `Select-Object` solution that constructs *new* custom-object instances that contain all of the input object's properties (`*`) plus a new *calculated* property that contains the combined column values of interest:

```sh
$o | Select-Object *, @{ n='Joined'; e={ 
  @(($_.psobject.Properties.Where({$_.Name -match 'Column*'})).Value) -ne 'null' -join ', ' } 
}
```

This solution is slower than the one above, but not by much.
A caveat is that if you collect all output in memory, the newly constructed objects take up space in addition to the originals.

---

#### Optional reading: Performance comparison; the impact of pipeline use:

The code at the bottom times the various approaches from Frode's and my answer.

Here's a sample timing from my machine - the absolute numbers aren't important, but their ratios are (though I don't know how factors such as CPU core count and disk speed would come into play) - input set size is `1000` objects:

```sh
Approach                                 TotalSeconds
--------                                 ------------
add-member w/ scriptproperty - operators 0.35
select-object w/ noteproperty            0.40
add-member w/ scriptproperty - pipeline  0.72
add-member w/ noteproperty - pipeline    0.98
```

Conclusions:

- The solutions that use pipelines in the property definition are noticeably slower, by a factor of about 2, which doesn't seem to vary even with larger input counts.
- The optimized `Select-Object`-based solution that creates *new* objects (rather than adding properties to the input objects) is only slightly slower than the optimized `Add-Member` solution.

**Source code for the tests:**

```sh
# The number of input objects to test with.
# Adjust to experiment.
$objCount = 1000

Write-Verbose -Verbose "# of input objects: $objCount"

$ndx = 0; $approaches = 'select-object w/ noteproperty', 
                        'add-member w/ scriptproperty - operators', 
                        'add-member w/ scriptproperty - pipeline', 
                        'add-member w/ noteproperty - pipeline'
$tempFile = New-TemporaryFile # requires PSv5+
$(foreach($approach in $approaches) {

  # Create test collection (recreate it in every iteration to support repeated Add-Member operations)
  $al = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
  for ($i = 0; $i -lt $objCount; ++$i) {
    $null = $al.add([pscustomobject] @{ one = 1; Column1 = 'col1'; Column2 = 'col2'; Column3 = 'null'; Column4 = 'col4' })
  }

  Measure-Command {

    Write-Verbose -Verbose "Running: $approach..."
    switch ($ndx) {
      0 { # select-object w/ noteproperty
        $al | Select-Object *, @{ n='Joined'; e={ @(($_.psobject.Properties.Where({ $_.Name -match 'Column*'})).Value) -ne 'null' -join ', ' } } | 
          Export-Csv $tempFile  
        break
      }
      
      1 { # add-member w/ scriptproperty - operators
        $al | Add-Member -PassThru -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name Joined -Value { @($this.psobject.Properties.Where({ $_.Name -match 'Column*'}).Value) -ne 'null' -join ', ' } |
          Export-Csv $tempFile          
        break
      }
      
      2 { # add-member w/ scriptproperty - pipeline
        $al | Add-Member -PassThru -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name Joined -Value { ($this.psobject.Properties | Where-Object { $_.Name -match 'Column*'  -and $_.Value -ne 'null' } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value) -join ', ' }  | 
         Export-Csv $tempFile
         break
        }
        
        3 { # add-member w/ noteproperty - pipeline; requires an intermediate ForEach-Object call
          $al | ForEach-Object {
            $_ | Add-Member -PassThru -NotePropertyName Joined -NotePropertyValue (($_.psobject.Properties | Where-Object { $_.Name -match 'Column*' -and $_.Value -ne 'null' } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value) -join ', ' )
          } |
            Export-Csv $tempFile
        break
      }
      default { Throw "What are you doing here?" }
    }

    # Import-Csv $tempFile | Select-Object -First 1 Joined | Write-Verbose -Verbose

    ++$ndx
        
  } | Select-Object @{ n='Approach'; e={ $approach }}, @{ n='TotalSeconds'; e={ '{0:N2}' -f $_.TotalSeconds } }

}) | Sort-Object { [double] $_.TotalSeconds }

Remove-Item $tempFile
```